# Browsers not updating when sockets get emmited

Tags: node.js, sockets, chat, livechat

I'm trying to create a chat system. Here it is:
[image]

The top field takes the name of the user while the bottom textarea takes the message. Once the user pressed enter the middle textarea ( which is disabled) updates itself with the new record. This is done using nodejs sockets. My problem is that if I open another instance of google chrome and I type something the other google chrome textarea does not update. I'm puzzled by this since my code should cover this case:

Here is the server.js code that handles the insertion. After it inserts it, it emits a socket with the last insertion so that the index.html can update itself.

```
io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
socket.on("send",function(data){

    mongodb.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDatabase",function(err,db){
        if(err) throw err;
        var to_be_inserted = {name: data.name,content: data.content};
        db.collection("chat").insert(to_be_inserted,function(err,objects){
            if(err) throw err;

            var cursor = db.collection("chat").find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(1);

            cursor.toArray(function(err,docs){
                console.log("abc");
                socket.emit("data_to_be_printed",docs);
            });

        });
    })
})
```

})

As you can see once the data is inserted a socket is emitted containing the last row of the db. The index.html should handle this socket by updating itself. Here is the code that handles it:

```
           <script>
            var socket = io.connect("127.0.0.1:1337");


            socket.on("data_to_be_printed",function(cursor){

                var completed = document.getElementById("chatArea").value;
                for(var i=0; i < cursor.length; i++)
                {
                    console.log(cursor[i].name + " wrote: " + cursor[i].content);
                    var name = cursor[i].name;
                    var content = cursor[i].content;
                    var name_to_go = name.replace("/\r?\n|\r/g","");
                    var content_to_go = content.replace("/\r?\n|\r/g","");
                    completed+="\n" + name_to_go + ": " + content_to_go;



                }

                document.getElementById("chatArea").value = completed;

            });

                function keyfunction(e)
                {

                    if((e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey)
                    {
                        socketEmitDb();

                    }

                }

                function socketEmitDb()
                {
                    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                    var content = document.getElementById("writtenThing").value;
                    console.log("Name: " + name + " |||| content: " + content);

                    document.getElementById("name").value="";
                    document.getElementById("writtenThing").value="";
                    if(name.length > 0 && content.length > 0)
                    {   

                        socket.emit("send",{"name": name,"content": content});

                    }else
                    {
                        alert("Make sure that the name and the message is not empty");
                    }

                }

       </script>
```

Should't the socket be emitted towards all opened sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server program change `socket.emit` to `io.sockets.emit`.

`socket.emit` will send message to specific socket (client) that got connected. `io.sockets.emit` will send message to all connected sockets (clients)

Comment: so the socket that comes from the argument of the callback is simply the socket that just connected?